# Importing files in python code from other directories

Tags: python

I am having the following directory structure.

```
A--Ab
   |
   |--Abc--main.py
   |  
   |--Abd--*.py
   |
   Ac--*.py
```

I have placed `__init__.py` files in every directory. and I am importing the files as below when I am in directory `Abc`.This works fine when I am running the main.py file from inside the `Abc` directory.

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../.."))
```

But when I am trying to run the `main.py` file from `Ab` directory as `python Abc/main.py` , the import is not working.

I want to understand how can I fix this so that the imports can work , even if I am running the code from directory A or any other directory.

---

Updating dir structure

```
A--Ab
   |-config.py
   |-main.py 
   |-*.py
```

Comment: `python Abc/main.py`: don't do that if all of `Ab` is supposed to be a package: don't run modules as a script.

Comment: `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../.."))`: don't do that either. With a proper installation, no modifications to sys.path should be necessary, and altering this will surprise an actual user.

Comment: would like to know the correct way @9769953

Comment: That depends on your goal(s). If your Python files are a bunch of scripts (which seems to be way you run `Abc/main.py`), you should restructure your directory layout. If your directory structure is a package, with subpackages/subdirectories and modules (as seem to be indicated by the use of `__init__.py`, then your scripts should be stored *outside* of that whole package structure (outside the `Ab` directory, or possibly the `A` directory, depending on where your package root is).

Comment: @9769953 i have updated the question with dir structure. is this what you are suggesting?

Comment: Try looking at [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder).